# A/B test group setup accounting for conversion rates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm trying to create an A/B test with treatment and control group to balance conversion rates and sales count across the 50 states for an experiment.

Example of non-aggregated data:

Null would be considered not converted (0) and IDs with a first sale date would be considered converted (1)

```
id | state | first sale
-------------------------
 1 | VA    | 2022-02-07
 2 | CA    | Null
 3 | CA    | 2022-03-15
 4 | CA    | 2022-04-05
 5 | TX    | 2022-05-12
 6 | TX    | Null
 7 | TX    | Null
 8 | TX    | Null
 9 | NJ    | Null
10 | NY    | 2022-04-17
 11| AZ    | 2022-03-07
 12| AZ    | NULL
 13| AZ    | 2022-04-13
```

Example of aggregated data:

```
State| Sales | Conversion
-------------------------
| VA  | 25  | .15
| CA  | 30  | .2
| TX  | 27  | .17
| AZ  | 22. | .22
```

Ideal final output:
Treatment and control each have 25 states. The conversion difference b/w treatment and control is < 1% and the sales count difference is also minimized. I can use the aggregated data above to create a column with "treatment" or "control"

```
Cohort.   | Sales Count | Conversion
Treatment | 250        | 0.2
Control.  | 248        | 0.195
```

Output: Based on minimizing the differences above we create a column to distinguish IDs with states for treatment and control.

```
id | state | first sale| Cohort|
-----------------------
 1 | VA    | 2022-02-07|Treatment
 2 | CA    | Null.     |Control
 3 | CA    | 2022-03-15|Control
 4 | CA    | 2022-04-05|Control
 5 | TX    | 2022-05-12|Treatment
```

Ideally I'd like to first reduce the conversion difference between the treatment and control, but also ensure the raw count of sales doesn't differ by more than a few percent. Any help for the code setup for this A/B test setup would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have a goal metric (??) and guard metric (raw sales). I don't know how to guide here but you can use evan miller's or neil patel's calculator to identify number of observation to obtain the difference (delta) you need.